# Cannot get pagination to work with view model asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

i have checked out the other questions/answers on here but none seemed to work with my senario.

Here is my viewmodel:

```
 public class EmployeeListViewModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public PaginatedList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    }
```

Top of view:

```
@model MMSystem.ViewModels.EmployeeListViewModel
```

Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? pageNumber)
        {
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;


            var employeeList = (from e in _context.Employees
                                join s in _context.Employees on e.Id equals s.SupervisorId
                                select new { Employee = s, Supervisor = e.FullName });


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                employeeList = employeeList.Where(e => e.Employee.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                       ||e.Employee.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            return View(new EmployeeListViewModel { Employees = await PaginatedList<Employee>.CreateAsync(employeeList.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize) });

        }
```

And this is my error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QJR9.png)

I have been trying everything to get it to work, but there seems to always be conversion or type conflict issues. (Note: everything worked fine prior to trying to add pagination)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, we can find that your code snippet (as below) return a list of anonymous objects which contains `Employee` and `Supervisor` properties.

> `var employeeList = (from e in _context.Employees
>                       join s in _context.Employees on e.Id equals s.SupervisorId
>                       select new { Employee = s, Supervisor = e.FullName });`

And at this code snippet `await PaginatedList<Employee>.CreateAsync(employeeList.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize)`, it can not explicitly convert anonymous object list to System.Linq.IQueryable, which causes the issue.

> cannot convert from '`System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: MMSystem.Models.Employee Employee, string Supervisor>>`' to '`System.Linq.IQueryable<MMSystem.Models.Employee>`'

To fix it, you can try modify the code like below.

```
return View(new EmployeeListViewModel { Employees = await PaginatedList<Employee>.CreateAsync(employeeList.Select(s=>s.Employee).AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize) });
```

Besides, you can refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-paging-to-students-index) with example that shows how to implement paging etc functionality.